# upload_max_filesize, php.ini, and Google App Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

I have a PHP 5.5 application running on Google App Engine. It's based on the CodeIgniter framework. Recently I started needing to upload files more than 8 MB.

I have been getting the following error

```
PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 8501809 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

I edited php.ini (which is in the same directory as app.yaml), but it doesn't seem to impact the maximum upload size.

```
post_max_size = "16M"
upload_max_filesize = "16M"
memory_limit = "128M"
```

Is there somewhere else I should be setting the max_size? Any other fields?

Thanks!

Comment: Solved! It turns out I had mixed and matched colons and equal sings in my `php.ini` file, and it was not formed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PHP runtime Directives](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime) documentation may be useful.  As you indicated,  [php.ini](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/php_ini) file should be in the same directory as your app.yaml.  I'd sugest specifically looking at the `file_uploads` and `max_file_uploads` values.  (Note that the default for each is 0, try setting it to 1).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this in my .htaccess file (this works well on shared hosting where you might not be able to change php.ini):

```
## I need more memory to upload large image
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value memory_limit 256M
  php_value post_max_size 50M
  php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
</IfModule>
```

further: in Codeigniter you can set filesize preference in your config.php file: see [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#setting-preferences)

Answer (score 1):

I added below in php.ini (same place where app.yaml is located) it worked

```
post_max_size = &quot;16M&quot;
upload_max_filesize = &quot;16M&quot;
memory_limit = &quot;128M&quot;
```