# Codeigniter - cannot upload file .pdf in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, upload, document

I want to upload a pdf file, but that file cannot be uploaded if the file size is over 3 MB

this is my config:

```
$config = array(
    'upload_path'=>'./assets/file/',
    'allowed_types' => 'pdf',
    'overwrite' => TRUE,
    'max_size' => '0',
    'file_name' => $_FILES['file_peta']['name']
);
```

Comment: The upload library configuration is only part of your problem. Even if Codeigniter is not limiting the file size, both your PHP installation and your server software (be it Apache or Nginx) do have their own limits. By default, PHP limits uploads to 2Mb and, IIRC, so do Apache and Nginx. You need to work on those limits too, as the effective constraint is determined by the lowest allowed value of the 3 (your code, PHP and your server directives)

Comment: here are some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46653262/2275490

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is only one link in the chain. Even though in your upload library you're not limiting the maximum file size, there's two more places where you need to check:

1.- PHP's configuration directives
2.- Either Nginx or Apache's configuration directives.

Each of the former have their one max upload size directive. The real limit in your case is the lower boundary of the three, so you need to check on those configurations (or have your system's administrator do it for you) and set a limit that works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

$config['max_size'] = '100';

$config['max_width'] = '1024';

$config['max_height'] = '768';
```

Visit http://zainhub.com/ regularly!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. While this may answer the question, it would be a lot more useful if you were to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

here is code snippets you can follow that :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class UploadFileController extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            // add these lines
            $this->load->library('upload'); 
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        }
        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('home', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }
        public function do_upload(){
            $config = array(
                'upload_path' => "./uploads/", // here add directory path where you want to upload and do not forget to give permission
                'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf", // you can add many more types
                'overwrite' => TRUE,
                'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                'max_height' => "768",
                'max_width' => "1024"
            );
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $this->load->view('upload_success',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->load->view('home', $error);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```