# File upload failing with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, file-upload

Am trying to upload pdf file which are over 90mb. But codeigniter keeps giving me the below error

> You did not select a file to upload

I dont know why this is happening. I updated the max execution time to 0 and max upload size to 200mb in php.ini on the server. Pdf files less than 5mb gets uploaded. When I tried a pdf file of 8mb it gives me the above error. I have not mentiond anything like allow only less than mb or such anywhere that I know of. Will paste the code below. Plase look and advice. Thank you

```
                 $config['upload_path']   = 'notes'; 
                 $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|jpg|png'; 
                 $config['max_size']      = 1000000; 
                 $config['max_width']     = 51024; 
                 $config['max_height']    = 51768;  
                 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    
                 if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
                    $this->load->view('uploadfail', $error); 
                 }else { 
                     $udata =  $this->upload->data();
                   $data = array('image_metadata' =>  $udata);
                }
```

Html code below.

```
              <div class="col-md-12" id="importFrm" style="display: block;">
        <form action="<?php echo base_url().'mcq/notes_import/'.$chid; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" class="btn btn-success float-right" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" name="uploadSubmit" value="UPLOAD">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the value of post max size in your php settings ?

Comment: Post max size is 55mb. I did set  ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','900M');  in my controller

Comment: Also increase the post max size

Comment: But files below 10mb shouldn't be a problem. Right? Will do it and check.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46653262/2275490

Comment: @Vickel his actual problem was some thing to do with typing error. But let me try the mentioned too.

Comment: @Andreas I have changed the post max size to 550mb. and set max input vars to ini_set('max_input_vars', 9000); in my controller. Still no result.

Comment: Is there anything in Apache settings that I might need to change.